# Adding a module to Wildfly while running

Tags: module, directory, wildfly

What happens when I add a module to Wildfly while it is running? I mean if I phisically copy under the modules directory a new directory with all my artifacts, what does it do?
Is it aware of the new directory and why? Or the module will be loaded at the next restart?

Comment: As far as I aware on next restart. Have you tried the other scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modules are lazyingly loaded so it won't get loaded until it is required.